# Support image file upload in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, file-upload, .net-core, image-uploading, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a Web API with .Net Core, where I need to allow a client to upload a list of files (mostly images) and save them to the server.

The problem is that when the image is uploaded, and I try to open it from the folder where it was saved, it seems like it's corrupted and its size is not the same as the initial one.

**Here is the code of my controller:**

```
[Route("api/TestUpload")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public class TestUploadController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public TestUploadController(ApplicationContext context, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _context = context;
        _env = env;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        var uploads = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "uploads");

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, formFile.FileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, formFile.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(new { size });
    }
}
```

The only files that seem to be uploaded and saved fine are text and html files. I've tried with a single file instead of a list, same thing.

I've tried several code variations and none seem to work, I'm probably doing something wrong but I just can't figure out what it is.

Here is a screenshot of a **test with Advanced REST client**:
[ARC screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyAoW.png)

And here is what I mean by **"it seems like it's corrupted"**: [Windows Photo Viewer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynaUh.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add a byte count to beginning of message.  The on receive end extract byte count and read until the entire message is received.   Filestream when you read from a File Synchronously the windows operating system puts a null at end of file.  When you are reading from a file Async there is no blocking so you return immediately.  The await does nothing in this case.

Comment: Strange, since your image suggest the incomming `size` is to small. How are you uploading this file?

Comment: @jdweng But I've tried using just `formFile.CopyTo(fileStream);` instead of doing it asynchronously but nothing changes.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I'm not going beyond the file size limitations as far as I know. I'm using the Adavanced REST client, and choosing `multipart/form-data` as the `content type`.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong in your code. `Flush` is unecessary and can be removed, but I don't think that's causing the issue. Are you sure the files are good to begin with?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, I've tried removing `Flush` but nothing changes. And yes, I'm 100% sure that the files are good, I can open them alright, the ones I'm trying to upload. I've also tried creating a simple form instead of using ARC but still the same thing:
`<form action="http://localhost:51113/api/TestUpload/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_">   
        <label>Files</label>
        <input type="file" name="files"/>

        <input type="submit" />
</form>`

Answer (score 1):

The are two problems which may cause confusion here:

1. Media types which are supported by service which define what formats of data can be uploaded correctly to the server.
2. Format of image uploaded which is different than image stored on source computer since none of image media format is supported by yur WebAPI.

In case like your WebAPI client HTTP POST message contains a payload - image, in HTTP header the Content-Type specifies the format of the message body. This tells the Web API how to parse the contents of the message body. For example, if an HTTP post message to your API contains a PNG image, the POST request might have the following headers:

```
Content-Length: 95267
Content-Type: image/png
```

Adding correct media formats attributes to you WebAPI controller class shuld support indicated in them image formats:

> ```
> [Route("api/TestUpload")]
> [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
> [Consumes("image/jpg")]
> [Consumes("image/png")]
> [Consumes("image/gif")]
> public class TestUploadController : Controller
> {
> }
> ```

In the case of any further problems or need to support image formats not available out of box create custom `MediaFormatter` clas derived from for instance `BufferedMediaFormatter` and use it in your project.

Comment: I can't add multiple `[Consumes]` annotations.